# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) working with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api, router

I am a beginner developer, and I am working on my own application for practice. Because of that, sorry if the question is poorly planned or very basic.

I am working with Vue.js, and when I try to consume the API using fetch, I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: Server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

It is important to note that the error only appears to me on the dynamic route that I created previously. I mean it works perfectly in the router view.

Here's my code:

api.js:

```
const url = "https://api.covid19api.com";

function getSummary() {
  return fetch(`${url}/summary?limit=20`) 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => res.Countries);
}

function getCountry(Country) {
  return fetch(`${url}/summary/${Country}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => res.Countries);
}

export default {
  getSummary,
  getCountry
};
```

CountryDetail.vue component:

```
<script>
import api from "@/api";

export default {
  name: "CountryDetail",

  data() {
    return {
      countrySelected: {}
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.getCountryName();
  },

  methods: {
    getCountryName() {
      const GET_COUNTRY = this.$route.params.Country;
      api
        .getCountry(GET_COUNTRY)
        .then(countrySelected => (this.countrySelected = countrySelected));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

router.js:

```
import CountryDetail from "@/views/CountryDetail";

Vue.use(Router); //Use permite agregar funcionalidades y escalar en requerimientos.

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",

  routes: [
    {
      path: "/country/:Country",
      name: "country-detail",
      component: CountryDetail
    }
  ]
});
```

When I load this url as example:
http://localhost:8081/country/Argentina

I got this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image]

Just in case, this is the API I'm using at the moment:
https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc?version=latest#6fbc46d6-0ddf-400b-a743-a149e9bba381

Comment: What server are you using to serve traffic on `http://localhost:8081`? Where do you see the error?

Comment: Hi, Phil! Well, now things suddenly changed and now I'm getting the fellow error: 
api.js?d722:10 GET https://api.covid19api.com/summary/undefined 404 (Not Found).

It is the very first thing I read when I load the page:
https://imgur.com/oON3Y4S.

Sorry if I'm not being clear enough. Thank you!

Comment: Route params are case sensitive. You want `this.$route.params.Country` (capital "C")

Comment: The 404 is a response to the server which means you are looking for something that cannot be found. It looks like you are looking for the country Argentina. Are you sure Argentina is defined in that database and can be fetched like that?

Comment: I just tried it but the error still continues. I'm kind of stuck and I don't know what else to do to be honest.

Comment: @FrancoAlemandi you tried what, exactly. If you've changed your code, please update your question

Comment: Hi Programmingjoe! Well, in the API Documentation I can see it:
{
      "Country": "Argentina",
      "CountryCode": "AR",
}

So I guess it is (please if you dont'mind you can check it in the API's link).

Comment: @Phil I put the capital C in ```this.$route.params.country``` as you said. I just edited the question, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I just had a look at that API documentation you linked and there is no `/summary/{country}` endpoint. There is only [`/summary`](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10808728/SzS8rjbc?version=latest#00030720-fae3-4c72-8aea-ad01ba17adf8). I think you need to take a closer look at the documentation. From the examples, it also looks like you should be using the country `slug` in URLs, not the `name`

Comment: Thank you @Phil! So it's the error, now I'll see how to make it works.